# Simplified cross joins?

Tags: t-sql

Let's sat I have a Table 'A' with rows:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Is there a simple way to do a cross join that creates

```
A  1
A  2
A  3
A  4
...
D  1
D  2
D  3
D  4
```

without creating a second table?

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
  CROSS JOIN (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that should work, i guess

```
select * from A cross join (select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4) as tmp
```

you will create a second table, but you won't persist it.

Answer (score 1):

The following would work for a table of any size (though I only tested it against 6 rows). It uses the ranking functions available in SQL Server 2005 and up, but the idea should be adaptible to any RDBMS.

```
SELECT ta.SomeColumn, cj.Ranking
 from TableA ta
  cross join (select row_number() over (order by SomeColumn) Ranking from TableA) cj
 order by ta.SomeColumn, cj.Ranking
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this via

```
select * from A cross join
(select 1
  union all
 select 2
  union all
 select 3
  union all
 select 4)
```